# Redirect Wordpress Sub Folder to a Sub Domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that is actually a multisite using subdomains and I would like to remap the subfolder translations to a sub domain.

```
domain.com (main site)
blog.domain.com (mu site for the blog)
```

With WPML, I have:

```
domain.com/fr/ (for the French translation)
blog.domain.com/fr/ (for the French translation)
```

I would like to have the following:

```
domain.com/fr/ --> fr.domain.com
blog.domain.com/fr/ --> blogue.domain.com
```

I think this could be possible with Rewrite rules, but I can't get it to work properly.

Here is the current default Wordpress MU .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://fr.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://blogue.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Almost there! The redirection does work, domain.com/fr goes to fr.domain.com but the Wordpress MU takes over and ask if I want to create a new fr.domain.com sub site. Isin't there a way to display fr.domain.com but process domain.com/fr in the background? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately changing `fr.domain.com` to `domain.com` will make it an external redirect. Only way possible is to use `mod_proxy` and use `P` flag (this will require enabling mod_proxy in Apache config)

Comment: This is a new project so everything is possible. :) Do you have more information on that mod_proxy change I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure, once you make sure `mod_proxy` is enabled you can change the `fr.domain` rule to: `RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://fr.domain.com/$1 [NC,P,L]`

Comment: I currently work locally on MAMP Pro and I double checked the phpinfo so that all these are enabled: mod_proxy mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_scgi mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer. The redirection still gets to Wordpress MU instead of "masking" the real URL.

Comment: Are you seeing URL changing in the browser with `[NC,P,L]` flags? If yes then `mod_proxy` is not activated somehow.

Comment: When using Web Sniffer locally, and entering domain.com/fr/ I get a 302 and Location: http://domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=fr as the redirect. Does this mean that the mod_proxy is not kicking in and just redirecting my request?

Comment: Yes your URL `domain.com/fr/` should not change in browser to `fr.domain.com` is mod_proxy is working fine and you are using `P` flag. Also try testing from a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/fr/ http://fr.domain.com/fr/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/fr/ http://blogue.domain.com/fr/ [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried to put it at the top of my .htaccess and just below the RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] line without any success. It does not seem to do anything :(